# How do I remove this fastener under my bathroom faucet

Tags: plumbing

What the heck is this brass fastener and how do I remove it?  It seems to be holding down my bathroom faucet which I'm trying to replace.

All I can think is that center "hinge" maybe unscrews somehow?  But I don't see any way to grip it, it doesn't have a shape I'm familiar with or that I know how to use with any of my tools (phillips, flathead, hex nut, wrench).

[image: fastener]
[image: another view]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a toggle nut with some type of locking device extending down through it.  It must be removed from above.  Some type of cover on the faucet itself is removable. From there you will see the top of the bolt that is threaded into that toggle nut. unscrew that bolt and the toggle will drop away.

Comment: You're right!  I removed the drain-control lever at top of faucet and was able to stick phillips head in that hole, and it worked.  Thanks!  Never would have found it.

Comment: Just for completeness: the reason for using this kind of fastener is that with some sinks it can be really hard to reach that fastener. When the faucet installed the fastener is already on the bolt, and the faucet is installed from above, pushing the fastener down through the hole. When it gets below the bottom of the hole the wings open out, and all you need to do is make sure the fastener doesn’t turn while you tighten the bolt from above.

Comment: Some of the smarter faucets are trying to make it so you don't have to do all the work under the faucet anymore. I bought a couple of Pfisters recently that have a separate nut you screw onto the water line first, then slide onto the faucet water lines and attach with a kotter pin. Makes life easy

Comment: thanks for that.  I didn't know.  Manufacturer's continue to do great things.